# L1-norm minimization

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

This is undoubtedly a trivial question but might as well ask: Why is the L1 norm minimization a heuristic for finding the sparsest vector? What I mean is that if the L1 norm sums the elements of a vector, how would that ensure that I get v2 instead of v1 below?

v1 = [1 2 3 4 0 0 0]

sum(v1) = 10

v2 = [9 8 0 0 0 0 0] (sparsest)

sum(v2) = 17

Comment: The $1$-norm has no preference between a few large components and many small components.  The $2$-norm, on the other hand, greatly prefers many small components (which get squared and become negligible) to a few large components (which get squared and become huge).  The $1$-norm allows you to have a few large components, if that is what is required, whereas the $2$-norm almost forbids it.

Comment: I don't follow exactly because as far as I understand the 1-norm is the sum of the absolute values of the elements in the vector. By that count I should get v1, but v2 is sparsest. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think of the unit ball in this norm: it is shaped like a diamond or octahedron or generalizations thereof. The 'spikes' on this ball lie on the coordinate axes where all but one coordinate is 0. Minimizing something in this norm amounts to take larger and larger L1 balls until one intersects the set you are minimzing. Since the spikes stick out the most, you are more likely to hit there first.

Comment: This helps me get a better picture of minimization using this norm but I'm still a little confused. Please see my comment under littleO's.

Comment: @val it doesn't always work, its just a heuristic. Its easy to construct counterexamples; but the idea is that the L1 norm is always at least as sparse as L2, even if its not that sparse itself.

Comment: " it doesn't always work, its just a heuristic." Thanks very much! I was stuck thinking otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Sparsity is actually the 0-norm or the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) to the 0 vector. Constant cost added whenever anything starts to differ from 0, but does not care by how much. So you can write

```
sum(v1!=0), sum(v2!=0)  % Hamming distance to 0 vector, a.k.a. 0 Norm.
```

The thing is 1-norm minimization is able to approximate 0-norms better than 2-norm minimization (you already got good explanation with diamonds and balls I think?) and there have been development in algorithms to solve 1-norm minimizations the last 10-15 years or so.